# Jquery click function for a div, but not for link inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click function, when user clicks anywhere in the div, it runs successfully. However, there is a link inside the div. If user clicks the link, I dont want to run the function, so that user goes to the link url when click.

html

```
<div id="container">
<a href="http://www.example.org"></a>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document.body).on('click', '[id="container"]' ,function(){
// do whatever
});
```

Which method should I use to achieve that ?

Answer (score 4):

You can check the target of the click as follows:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#container' ,function(e){
    if (e.target.id !== 'container') return; // not the element we want
    // do whatever
});
```

Or, if any other child of the `div` should be allowed, except if it is an `a` element, then:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#container' ,function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName === 'A') return; // not the element we want
    // do whatever
});
```

Comment: FYI `[id="container"]` is usually written as `#container`

Comment: FYI, its because content is dynamically added.

Comment: FYI you can still use `'#container'`

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you do something like this, should work:

```
    $("#container a").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#container").on("click",function(e){

        if(e.target.tagName == "DIV") {
            fun();
        }


        else if(e.target.tagName == "A") {
            e.stopPropagation();
            }


    })

    function fun() {
        alert("Run function");
    }
})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">div
           <a href="http://www.example.org">Link</a>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#container").on("click",function(e){

            if(e.target.tagName == "DIV") {
                fun();
            }


            else if(e.target.tagName == "A") {
                e.stopPropagation();
                }


        })

        function fun() {
            alert("Run function");
        }
    })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a',function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```